# Creating Item/Product in Netsuite from Restlet

Tags: .net, rest, netsuite

How to create item/product in Netsuite via Restlet. WHich object/API name I should use to create an item ?
Please provide code snippet if possible.

Comment: did you mean standard netsuite `item` record?

Answer (score 0):

if you know how to code using SuiteScript then it will be an easy thing for you.

you can use nlapiCreateRecord API.

Comment: Hi @vVinceth,
how did you are creating an invoice for those customer who doesn't have credit limit, i am facing issue, i would appreciate if you can share with me some detail

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686093/how-to-create-invoice-in-netsuite-using-suitetalk